# How to retrieve data from 3 tables using sub query oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

I want to retrieve users name and there `responsibility_key` where there end_date  is  null and i want to  convert it to  (sysdate+1) using nvl  but i am only able to retrieve the responsibility_key not the name please help.

[image]

Comment: Please post your sql in the question and not as an image

Answer (score 2):

The error in the image says "column ambiguously defined". Take a close look. Your last `END_DATE` could refer to either the `u` alias or the table from the subquery. Change it to match the rest of your subquery (`FIND_USER_GROUPS_DIRECT.END_DATE`)

**EDIT**

Your query is

```
select u.USER_NAME, d.responsibility_key   from FND_USER u,FND_RESPONSIBILITY_VL  d
where responsibility_id in(
select responsibility_id from
FND_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT   WHERE END_USER_RESP_GROUPS_DIRECT.END_DATE=nvl(END_DATE,sysdate+1)) and
u.END_DATE=nvl(END_DATE,SYSDATE + 1)
;
```

1. The query isn't formatted, which makes it hard to read.
2. Not all columns are qualified with table name (or aliases), as mentioned in the comments.
3. The query currently uses an implicit join.
4. The query is impossible to understand without seeing the table definitions (`desc [table_name]`).

For points 1 and 2, a properly formatted query will look something like

```
select u.user_name, d.responsibility_key
from 
    fnd_user u,
    fnd_responsibility_vl d
where 
    d.responsibility_id in (
        select urgd.responsibility_id 
        from
            fnd_user_resp_groups_direct urgd
        where 
            urgd.end_date = nvl(u.end_date, sysdate+1)
    ) and
    u.end_date = nvl(urgd.end_date, sysdate + 1)
;
```

This makes it easier to read and in addition to this, you can see that without table definitions **I guessed** (see point 4) as to which tables the `end_date` column belongs in your query. If I had to guess, so does Oracle. That means you have an ambiguity problem. To fix it, take a close look at the `end_date` column as it appears in your original query and where you do not prefix it with anything, you need to prefix it with the appropriate alias (after you have aliased all your tables).

For point 3, you can write your query more clearly with an explicit join and by using aliases for all columns.  As for the explicit join I have no idea what your tables look like but one possibility is something like

```
select u.user_name, d.responsibility_key 
from fnd_user u
join fnd_responsibility_vl d
on u.id = d.user_id
where
    d.responsibility_id in (
        select responsibility_id 
        from fnd_user_resp_groups_direct urgd
        where
            urgd.end_date = nvl(u.end_date, sysdate+1)
    ) and
    u.end_date = nvl(urgd.end_date, sysdate+1)
;
```

If you follow these points you will get to the root of the error.

Comment: @mekdi, you should **always** qualify **all** columns with table names (or, even better, table aliases) they belong to. Review your code and fix that. Without it, your code is a) invalid (obviously; Oracle told you so), b) it will be difficult to debug a week or two later as you'd forget which table contains which columns), not to mention someone else who'd have to do that.